# Get list of all genetic combinations from multidimensional array

Tags: php

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
[13] => Array
    (
        [0] => aa
    )

[17] => Array
    (
        [0] => Bb
        [1] => bb
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [0] => CC
        [1] => Cc
        [2] => cc
    )
)
```

Each element of the array represents a gene (so the keys 13, 17, and 14 are important to keep track of which gene goes where) with one to three possibilities for that gene.

How can I make an array that will contain a list of every possibility? I imagine it would look something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [13] => aa
            [17] => Bb
            [14] => CC
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [13] => aa
            [17] => Bb
            [14] => Cc
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [13] => aa
            [17] => Bb
            [14] => cc
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [13] => aa
            [17] => bb
            [14] => CC
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [13] => aa
            [17] => bb
            [14] => Cc
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [13] => aa
            [17] => bb
            [14] => cc
        )
)
```

Edit:
I have the following code taken from https://gist.github.com/farinspace/1126042#file_output.txt. This function does exactly what I need EXCEPT my keys are not sequential, which results in an invalid result. I am working to adjust it to use specified keys, however I am not there yet with it.

```
function combos($data, &$all = array(), $group = array(), $val = null, $i = 0) {
    if (isset($val)) {
        array_push($group, $val);
    }
    if ($i >= count($data)) {
        array_push($all, $group);
    } else {
        foreach ($data[$i] as $v) {
            combos($data, $all, $group, $v, $i + 1);
        }
    }
    return $all;
}
$data = array(
    array('a', 'b'),
    array('e', 'f', 'g'),
    array('w', 'x', 'y', 'z'),
);
$combos = combos($data);
```

Comment: Just for the reference: what you ask is "permutation".

Comment: It would help if you gave more information as at the moment there isn't enough information to be able to answer(IMHO) - but also you are normally expected to have tried some code for yourself first and post that to show you have made an effort rather than just ask others to solve it for you.

Comment: @user1597430 I'm looking for combinations, not permutations. The order doesn't matter. :)

Comment: @NigelRen I'll edit with code when I get home. Thanks!

Comment: @NigelRen I am really breaking my brain with this. I'm pretty sure I need recursion to do this properly. I tried editing that function with setting pointers to keep track of where I am in the array, and I ended up confusing myself even worse. It seems like it should be so straightforward, especially with such a concise example to go from. I have no idea how to change that function to use non-sequential keys instead of a counter. Help?